# Unable to sniff serial port. Weird behavior

Tags: serial-port

Trying to reverse an engineer a program that communicates with a device through a COM PORT. From monitoring the program, it sends 4 bytes of 0x00 and then the device replies back with the same and switches to flash mode. When I send the same bytes, the device does not respond, and in fact, no matter what I send, the serial port monitor says 0x00 is being written.

I've tried several different com port monitors, tried several different baud rates, flush com port before sending the command. Nothing seems to work. What could cause this type of issue?

Answer (score 0):

> no matter what I send, the serial port monitor says 0x00

From what you describe it seems like the serial sniffer you use is faulty.
Serial port sniffer I'm using successfully is this [Serial Analyzer](http://freeserialanalyzer.com/).

Comment: Eltima serial port monitor is now echoing read status timeout, and showing a fail for write commands. HHD serial monitor doesn't pick up anything